# Mode for group data

Tags: distributions

What would be my fx if my distribution table is like this:

```
Distribution   Frequency
1-5               9
6-10              7
11-15             8
16-20             3
```

fx is the frequency of the group before the modal group. The model group is 1-5 because it has the highest frequency of 9. So what will be my fx? Is it 0?

Comment: I'm sorry but I could not understand what you need. Are you trying to fit a model? What exactly is fx? Please clarify it a little if you could do so.

Comment: @Walter I'm trying to get the mode for my grouped data. fx is the frequency of the group before the modal group. I need it because it is in the formula for getting the mode in group data. I'm following it on this link: https://www.mathsisfun.com/data/frequency-grouped-mean-median-mode.html

Comment: Well, in that link it's fm-1. I just changed the symbol to fx just for clarification.

Comment: In that case the frequency of the previous class (so called fx) should be 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the link provided on question comments, the frequency of the previous class (so called fx) should be 0.